# method not working in flutter? can anyone help me

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make my text button fire a method from another class but it didn't work. The method that button should start:

```
void nextStory(int choiceNumber) {
    if (choiceNumber == 1 && _storyNum == 0) {
      _storyNum = 2;
    } else if (choiceNumber == 2 && _storyNum == 0) {
      _storyNum = 1;
    } else if (choiceNumber == 1 && _storyNum == 1) {
      _storyNum = 2;
    } else if (choiceNumber == 2 && _storyNum == 1) {
      _storyNum = 3;
    } else if (choiceNumber == 1 && _storyNum == 2) {
      _storyNum = 5;
    } else if (choiceNumber == 2 && _storyNum == 2) {
      _storyNum = 4;
    } else if (_storyNum == 3 || _storyNum == 4 || _storyNum == 5) {
      _storyNum = 0;
    }
```

[image: 1]

**textbutton:**

```
Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        storyBrainClass().nextStory(1);
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      storyBrainClass().getChoice1(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

[image: 2]

the idea of the app is the user can choose his own story, with his own choices:

[image: 3]
[image: 4]

**main.dart** file :

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:restart_app/restart_app.dart';
import 'storyBrain.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Destini());
}

class Destini extends StatelessWidget {
  const Destini({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: StoryPage(),
    );
  }
}

class StoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  StoryPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StoryPage> createState() => _StoryPageState();
}

class _StoryPageState extends State<StoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('images/1.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0, horizontal: 15.0),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 12,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    storyBrainClass().getStory(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        storyBrainClass().nextStory(1);
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      storyBrainClass().getChoice1(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        storyBrainClass().nextStory(2);
                        print('blue done');
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      storyBrainClass().getChoice2(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Clean Code advice: class names should start with a capital letter and should not contain the word class in its name. The fact that it is a class is obvious and does not need to be encoded into its name.

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what exactly is not working, or if there is any kind of unexpected behavior.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your code as per follow : `stackoverflow.com/questions/954570/definition-of-clean-code`

based on code understanding you can use return type function like

```
 List<story> _storyData = [];

  Future<story> nextStory(int choiceNumber) async {
    if (choiceNumber == 1 && _storyNum == 0) {
     return _storyData[2];
    }
    ---------
    else {
    return _storyData[0];
    }
  }
```